# Inserting and deleting XML nodes and elements using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to extract parts of an XML file and make a note that I extracted some part in that file, like "here something was extracted".

I'm trying to do this with Nokogiri, but it seems to not really be documented on how to:

1. delete all childs of a `<Nokogiri::XML::Element>`
2. change the `inner_text` of that complete element

Any clues?

Comment: Nokogiri's Tutorials for [Modifying an HTML / XML Document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html) cover this. Also `node.unlink` will remove it from a DOM.

Comment: See "[ask]". As is, this is lacking important information such as a minimal XML example for input and the expected output, plus the code that was written toward solving the problem.

Answer (score 17):

Nokogiri makes this pretty easy.  Using [this document](http://www.alistapart.com/d/usingxml/xml_uses_a.html) as an example, the following code will find all `vitamins` tags, remove their children (and the children's children, etc.), and change their inner text to say "Children removed.":

```
require 'nokogiri'

io = File.open('sample.xml', 'r')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(io)
io.close

doc.search('//vitamins').each do |node|
  node.children.remove
  node.content = 'Children removed.'
end
```

A given `food` node will go from looking like this:

```
<food>
    <name>Avocado Dip</name>
    <mfr>Sunnydale</mfr>
    <serving units="g">29</serving>
    <calories total="110" fat="100"/>
    <total-fat>11</total-fat>
    <saturated-fat>3</saturated-fat>
    <cholesterol>5</cholesterol>
    <sodium>210</sodium>
    <carb>2</carb>
    <fiber>0</fiber>
    <protein>1</protein>
    <vitamins>
        <a>0</a>
        <c>0</c>
    </vitamins>
    <minerals>
        <ca>0</ca>
        <fe>0</fe>
    </minerals>
</food>
```

to this:

```
<food>
    <name>Avocado Dip</name>
    <mfr>Sunnydale</mfr>
    <serving units="g">29</serving>
    <calories total="110" fat="100"/>
    <total-fat>11</total-fat>
    <saturated-fat>3</saturated-fat>
    <cholesterol>5</cholesterol>
    <sodium>210</sodium>
    <carb>2</carb>
    <fiber>0</fiber>
    <protein>1</protein>
    <vitamins>Children removed.</vitamins>
    <minerals>
        <ca>0</ca>
        <fe>0</fe>
    </minerals>
</food>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
doc=Nokogiri::XML(your_document)
note=doc.search("note") # find all tags with the node_name "note"
note.remove
```

While that would remove all children within the `<note>` tag, I am not sure how to "change the inner_text" of all note elements. I think `inner_text` is not applicable for a Nokogiri::XML::Element.

Answer (score 3):

The previous Nokogiri example set me in the right direction, but using `doc.search` left a malformed `//vitamins`, so I used CSS:

```
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"

f = File.open("food.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

doc.css("food vitamins").each do |node|
  puts "\r\n[debug] Before: vitamins= \r\n#{node}"
  node.children.remove
  node.content = "Children removed"
  puts "\r\n[debug] After: vitamins=\r\n#{node}"
end
f.close
```

Which results in:

```
debug] Before: vitamins= 
<vitamins>
        <a>0</a>
        <c>0</c>
    </vitamins>

[debug] After: vitamins=
<vitamins>Children removed</vitamins>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

Parse some XML first:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="nutrition.css"?>
<nutrition>

  <daily-values>
    <total-fat units="g">65</total-fat>
    <saturated-fat units="g">20</saturated-fat>
    <cholesterol units="mg">300</cholesterol>
    <sodium units="mg">2400</sodium>
    <carb units="g">300</carb>
    <fiber units="g">25</fiber>
    <protein units="g">50</protein>
  </daily-values>

  <food>
    <name>Avocado Dip</name>
    <mfr>Sunnydale</mfr>
    <serving units="g">29</serving>
    <calories total="110" fat="100"/>
    <total-fat>11</total-fat>
    <saturated-fat>3</saturated-fat>
    <cholesterol>5</cholesterol>
    <sodium>210</sodium>
    <carb>2</carb>
    <fiber>0</fiber>
    <protein>1</protein>
    <vitamins>
      <a>0</a>
      <c>0</c>
    </vitamins>
    <minerals>
      <ca>0</ca>
      <fe>0</fe>
    </minerals>
  </food>

</nutrition>
EOT
```

If I want to delete a node's content, I can remove its `children` or assign nil to its content:

```
doc.at('total-fat').to_xml # => "<total-fat units=\"g\">65</total-fat>"
doc.at('total-fat').children.remove
doc.at('total-fat').to_xml # => "<total-fat units=\"g\"/>"
```

or:

```
doc.at('saturated-fat').to_xml # => "<saturated-fat units=\"g\">20</saturated-fat>"
doc.at('saturated-fat').content = nil
doc.at('saturated-fat').to_xml # => "<saturated-fat units=\"g\"/>"
```

If I want to extract the text from a node for use some other way:

```
food = doc.at('food').text
# => "\n    Avocado Dip\n    Sunnydale\n    29\n    \n    11\n    3\n    5\n    210\n    2\n    0\n    1\n    \n      0\n      0\n    \n    \n      0\n      0\n    \n  "
```

or:

```
food = doc.at('food').children.map(&:text)
# => ["\n    ",
#     "Avocado Dip",
#     "\n    ",
#     "Sunnydale",
#     "\n    ",
#     "29",
#     "\n    ",
#     "",
#     "\n    ",
#     "11",
#     "\n    ",
#     "3",
#     "\n    ",
#     "5",
#     "\n    ",
#     "210",
#     "\n    ",
#     "2",
#     "\n    ",
#     "0",
#     "\n    ",
#     "1",
#     "\n    ",
#     "\n      0\n      0\n    ",
#     "\n    ",
#     "\n      0\n      0\n    ",
#     "\n  "]
```

or however else you want to mangle the text.

And, if you want to mark that you've removed the text:

```
doc.at('food').content = 'REMOVED'
doc.at('food').to_xml # => "<food>REMOVED</food>"
```

You could also use an XML comment instead:

```
doc.at('food').children = '<!-- REMOVED -->'
doc.at('food').to_xml # => "<food>\n  <!-- REMOVED -->\n</food>"
```